# CA1709 - Should we ignore this and use Db or DB?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, fxcop

I know it sounds silly, but in regards to [CA1709](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182240.aspx), should we ignore this error and just do what Microsoft did (which is use Db as the acronym for Database)?

Just wondering what people out there are doing. To me, it seems silly to use `DB` when Microsoft uses `Db` all over the place.

Comment: Personally I think the "Uppercase two letter acronyms" rule is stupid, since it loses information about where the different parts of an identifier start.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - as @ChrisWue points out, it's about consistency. Nearly every standard is stupid, arbitrary, or both in some case. Microsoft put a lot of time and research into theirs, and staying reasonably close to it results in a codebase familiar to a large number of developers. (My two cents.)

Comment: Then you lose the ability to automatically transform to a different convention. One application of this is json serialization where the convention is usually to separate different words with an `_`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, does it? Choose what you like best - but then make sure you use it consistently. With coding and naming conventions it's mainly about choosing one you like **and be consistent**

Answer (score 8):

Quoting Brad Abrams in the excellent [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613):

> ...I have heard every possible excuse for violating these naming
>   guidelines. [...] For the most part, our customers have seen the
>   places in which we have diverged from these guidelines (for even the
>   best excuse) as warts in the Framework.

In other words, do as they say, not as they do. :)

Also, 'Db' is an abbreviation, not an acronym. Database is one word. Abbreviations should never be used in identifiers per the Guidelines. ('Id' is a special case.)

Sadly the [CA1709 link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182240.aspx) lists 'DB' as an example. :(

Comment: So, is your answer stating that it should be 'DB' or 'Db'?

Comment: @m-y It should actually be "Database" per the Microsoft guidelines (which Microsoft doesn't always follow). I'd probably go with "Db" as in System.Data.Entity.DbContext - but as ChrisWue states, pick a standard for your team and be consistent.

Comment: Can you link to these guidelines, I could not find the actual link that states to use the full name 'Database' anywhere.

Comment: There's [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx), but I'd suggest buying the book (see link in my answer). There's so much more good advice in there.

Comment: The two letters 'Db' should be an exception in the same way that Id is. 
I always wondered who create the class 'DBNull', which stands as an exception across all our APIs.